# Gibbon::MailChimp Error (Invalid MailChimp List ID: ) - Learn Ruby On Rails - Kehoe

Tags: heroku, railsapps, learn-ruby-on-rails

I'm nearly done with the [Learn Ruby on Rails](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html) tutorial by Daniel Kehoe, but am having an issue after deploying to Heroku. Run from Nitrous, the app works perfectly, allowing me to sign up for a newsletter via MailChimp. When I pushed to Heroku, I get a "Gibbon::MailChimp Error (Invalid MailChimp List ID: )" error in the $heroku logs. I went through the source code on Github, and my code all seems to be correct. The API, list id, usernames and passwords are all correct. Help!

Comment: if its valid proably something is different in the environment vars. since that book costs money, I can't see the code that could cause problems. Check to see where the mailchimp id is (in code, in env var, etc)

Comment: The learn-rails code is all on Github https://github.com/RailsApps/learn-rails.  The environmental variables are correct, API and List ID stored in bash profile are correct, heroku configs are correct.

Comment: By process of elimination, it's likely that the problem is with your Heroku config. You can try asking Heroku support for help but check the config carefully and re-enter to make sure.

Comment: It was indeed in my heroku config - not an incorrect value, but the key. Instead of MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID, I had MAILCHIMP_LIST. Heroku Support spotted it. Great customer service!